# linux program segment faults

Tags: c, linux, shared, elf

Working on Ubuntu 10.04.

I was testing one of the gSOAP examples (calcclient) as a statically linked executable. It worked ok.
Later I splitted the modules so some of them went into a shared library (which I copied to /usr/local/lib). Then compiled the main module as a standalone dinamically linked binary.
All seems ok, the ldd output is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff66fff000)
libgsoapcalcclient.so => /usr/local/lib/libgsoapcalcclient.so (0x00007f7a59d35000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7a59986000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7a5a177000)
```

which is expected. 
But when I try to execute the binary it stops with a segmentation fault. 
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Compile with debugging information enabled and determine where the segfault occurred would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why (need to read carefully the generated makefile) but after I build a project on CodeLite the app compiled and ran without error. 
This is not the first time I ask something here and finish answering my question.